# Blank white screen on error with Kestrel ASP.NET 5

Tags: mono, asp.net-core

I'm trying to develop an asp.net 5 website using Mono and Kestrel development server. When the website compiles properly, I'm able to load the website without any dramas on the local development port after launching k kestrel

However, if there is an error with my .cshtml view file (referencing wrong model), or even something as simple as a null reference exception error, the Kestrel web server just returns a white screen of death, without any explanation to the cause of the error, either on the webpage (like the traditional asp.net yellow error pages) or within the terminal running Kestrel.

Is there any way that I can determine what is causing the error?I'm unable to determine the error within my view.

I'm currently using Linux Mint 17 with Mono 3.12.0 with KPM installed

Cheers, 
Justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you include the error middleware as shown [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/samples/MusicStore/Startup.cs)?

Comment: I was able to get this to successfully run using the UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute method. However, when I'm debugging, this line always renders a blank page (with no information at all, just a blank page with no markup).

app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);

Any ideas?

Comment: Attach a debugger or enable logging. Exceptions after the response starts can't be rendered in the browser.